# Is it possible to tell which application instance serves the request on Cloud Foundry?

Tags: instance, cloud-foundry

As you know, an application on Cloud Foundry could have more than 1 instances. Sometime, all or some of them need be configured through the HTTP Request, like altering the logger level. But due to the load balance, round-robin, one user's multiple requests may be routed to different instances. So, for the user, I didn't find a way to specify which instance to be configured, or tell which instance has already been configured.

Does anyone know this trick? Or is it possible to send HTTP request to all of the instances?

Answer (score 7):

You can send requests to specific instances by using X-CF-APP-INSTANCE header. For all of them just go one by one.

> "Users can route HTTP requests to a specific application instance
>   using the header X-CF-APP-INSTANCE. The format of the header should be
>   X-CF-APP-INSTANCE: APP_GUID:APP_INDEX."

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html#surgical-routing

Comment: Thanks @Anatoly for your so quick answer. It surely does the trick.

Comment: @Antoly I am also trying to hit an api on particular instance but it gives me error sometimes : 400 Bad Request: Requested instance ('1') with guid ('aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa') does not exist for route ('example-route.cf.com').

Comment: I am using the below command using CF CLI tool:                                                        
                                   curl -H <Authorization: Bearer <jwt>" -H  "X-Cf-App- 
      Instance":"<APP-GUID>:                              
  <INSTANCE-INDEX-NUMBER>" -X  <Request-Mapping> <Api-Uri>

Comment: **Eg :**  curl -H "Authorization: Bearer 0003uNnMOXUiYQLRliaxjiX6xbDR"
        -H "X-Cf-App-Instance":"3XXXXX37-48ac-495b-919d-474XXXXXXXX9:0" 
 -X GET https://iXXXXXXXs.api.xxxx.net/app-api-proxy/getDetailsById/XXXXXXX-XXXXX-atr56